# Different user schemas in mongo db with mongoose js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have different types of users(admin, employe, user) in my mongo db and I wanted to ask what the best strategy is to handle this scenario. 
1)Should I use [mongoose schema extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-schema-extend) so I can query on just one schema type(for example at registration) ?
2)Should I handle every user type for it self?
3)Is there a better solution you would recommend ?
4)Would you save permissions for each user type in the db or in a config file?

I guess the question is basic, but since I dont have any kind of experience on this field I am glad to get some good advise from you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends what you want to do.

- If users can have different sets of properties, I would suggest using a separate model per user type, and splitting your database into different collections per user type. I don't have experience with mongoose schema extend so I couldn't really comment on that, but it seems to be made for this scenario.
- If you have roles that you also need to account for, and that you want to store in the database (e.g. for easy configuration and changes later on), perhaps you should look into a relational database because in this case you're talking about relations (between the user and the roles) and MongoDB isn't really the best choice for that.
- If you don't need to store the user roles in your database (e.g. if they're hardcoded in your application) and your users don't have different properties, you could simply add a `usertype` property to your user model, and just check which value it has wherever you need it in your application.

*Disclaimer: I'm no MongoDB expert, this is just from my own experience :)*